# Нет изображения с web камеры

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток! есть код:

```
     Vector devices = CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(new YUVFormat());
     if (devices.size()<1) {
         System.out.println("No capture devices available!");  
        System.exit(1);
     } else {
      cam = (CaptureDeviceInfo)devices.elementAt(0);
     }

     player = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(cam.getLocator());

     Component comp;

     JFrame f = new JFrame();
     f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     f.setSize(640,480);

     if((comp = player.getVisualComponent()) != null )
     {
         Component controlPanel, visualComponent; 
         if ((controlPanel = player.getControlPanelComponent()) != null)
             f.add(controlPanel);

             f.add(visualComponent);

         player.start();
     }
     else{
         System.out.println("not visual component");
         System.exit(1);
     }

     f.setVisible(true);
```

проблема в том, что отображается только черный экран, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

В том, что у некоторых камер есть время полной инициализации, например когда камера включается, даёт картинку,а затем происходит автоконтраст и кадре на пятом-десятом уже нормальная картинка.
Попробуйте сделать 10 кадров в один сеанс.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: я уж не знаю, актуально ли, но вот в английской ветке отвечали http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276292/capturing-image-from-webcam-in-java, также там есть ответ про проект https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture, в котором тот же функционал выглядит очень компактно в коде.